# Hover ON / hover OFF. При обновлении OFF самопроизвольно анимируется

Tags: css3, css-animation, анимация, css

Приветы! Дело такое: есть "а" внутри которого "div".
При наведении мыши, А меняет цвет, а div анимируется. При снятии мыши с A — происходит обратная анимация.
Фокус в том, что при обновлении страницы, эта самая обратная анимация самопроизвольно запускается. А это мне нафиг не надо, как говорится. Вот линк на пример:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GqUFz/7/). Странно, но на фидле нет такого эффекта. При просмотре в localhost — есть.

Comment: Ну что, никто не знает!?
Цитирую товарища:
"Поставь флаг, чтобы анимировалось обратно только если уже была произведена первая анимация".
А потом он ускакал куда-то. ).

Comment: js мб можно сделать,

Comment: не показывать блок пока не загрузится полностью css.